# PHP's mysqli Closes Connection After Query

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run PHP on a server on my local machine, my database connection closes whenever I perform a mysqli->query().  I have a workaround for this issue, but can anyone tell me why this is happening and if there's a to prevent it?

For reference, here are the relevant PHP code snippets, output logs, and php.ini configuration values.

```
class mysqliDALUtility {
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        self::OpenNewConnection();
    }

    public function PerformQuery($queryString) {
        ...
        $result = self::QueryDB($queryString);
        ...
    }

    private function IsConnectionClosed() {
        return !$this->conn->stat();
    }

    private function OpenNewConnection() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli('p:127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pw', 'db');
    }

    private function QueryDB($queryString) {
        if (self::IsConnectionClosed()) {
            self::OpenNewConnection();
        }

        return $this->conn->query($queryString);
    }
}
```

When I add logging and perform two queries in a row, I find that the order of events is

1. Call the constructor and create a new connection
2. For query #1, use the existing connection
3. After the query the connection is closed
4. For query #2, create a new connection
5. After the query the connection is closed

My php.ini log contains

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
...

[MySQLi]

mysqli.max_persistent = -1
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
```

---

Also, I am using PHP version 5.6.11.

---

@libreman, I'm creating one Database Utility class instance and injecting it in to a number of other service classes, using constructor injection.

This is a simplified example, but my service class looks like this:

```
function __construct(mysqlDALUtility $dbUtility) {
   $this->db = $dbUtility;
}

public function serviceClassFunction() {
    $accessLevel = $this->db->PerformQuery("CALL usp_get_member_access_level('**********')");
    if ($accessLevel > 0) {
        $this->db->PerformQuery("CALL usp_get_dialogue_details(18,true);");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time mysqliDALUtility object is destructed the $conn variable is destroyed too, but keep in mind that does no mean the connection to your database is closed too, is good practice to close the connection in __destruct function also I think you must implement the singleton pattern any way could you post how are you using mysqliDALUtility object?

Comment: "is good practice to close the connection in __destruct function" --- is it?

Comment: Of course or you can get: a Too many connections error of course the most optimal is reusing the same connection so you no save network resourse, memory and time opening/closing new connections

Comment: How about the thing that php closes all connections *automatically* right before it returns? So doing it manually literally changes nothing.

Comment: Of course or you can get: a "Too many connections error" anyway the most optimal is reusing the same connection so you can save network resource, memory and time due you are not opening/closing new connections every time a php script is executed.

Comment: "Too many connections error" is irrelevant, since php would close the connection automatically. So there is no difference whether you close it or not.

Comment: I think If you do not do a mysqli_close connection then your connection to database remains open yet when $conn variables is destroyed, but i mentioned before the optimal is reuse the same connection maybe storing the connection object in memory cache so you can reuse it in every part of your application

Comment: @libreman, Let me add a simplified example up above, since I'm having trouble formatting it here.

Comment: @AmosLong every thing look ok with your logic maybe is your are using self inside non static function due you don't have static function I recommend you do a test using this instead of self.

Comment: @liberman, I changed my "self::" references to "$this->", but I still get the same result.

Comment: I think if you debug your app with a tool like: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/ and https://xdebug.org/ you can get a clue why your getting this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `p:` in `new mysqli('p:127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pw', 'db');`

As the [manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php),

> Prepending host by p: opens a persistent connection. mysqli_change_user() is automatically called on connections opened from the connection pool.

And when you read the manual for [mysql_change_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.change-user.php) it says

> Note:
>
> Using this command will always cause the current database connection to behave as if was a completely new database connection, regardless of if the operation was completed successfully. This reset includes performing a rollback on any active transactions, closing all temporary tables, and unlocking all locked tables.

Comment: I get the same behavior when I remove the "p:" from the ip address.  But I think I want to persist connections.

Comment: Why did you mention the "mysql_change_user()" note?  It does produce the result that I'm seeing, but I'm not calling it anywhere.

Comment: If you read the manual page it gets called by the API automatically

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I've removed the "p:" but still get the same result.  Any thoughts?